# PHP: Sending Serialized data to another php page using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send a serialzed data to another php page like below:

```
 $.ajax({
           url:"get_more_news.php?x1="+'<?php echo $x1 ?>',
           method: 'get',                                        
            success: function(data)
            {
            alert(data);                                                    
            }
       });
```

Here $x1 is a serialzed data. Now my concern is,

1.) Would it be a good practice to send the data like this.
2.) Would it create an issue if there is a single quotes in the serialzed data.(pls note that there are also quotes on get_more_news.php?x1="+'')

Comment: If your data generated on server - why send it to client and then get back?

Comment: @u_mulder : I am creating a facebook like news ticker. In the homepage, first all the news are generated using a multi-dimensional array. Now the issue is, I dont want to load all the news feed at once, so initially I am displaying only first 10 data for the array...and when the user clicks on a load more button then it should fetch more data from another file. thats why I am first sending the data to another page so that I can retireve it later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass some data I suggest you no use `json` format. Here how it can look like:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"get_more_news.php",
   method: 'get',                                        
   data: <? echo json_encode($x1) ?>,
   success: function(data)
   {
       alert(data);                                                    
   }
});
```

Where `json_encode` function will help you to overcome/avoid difficulties with quotes.

**Update**:

Suppose you want to send array like:

```
$array = ['x1' => 'value', 'x2' => 'another_value'];
```

In js-part you use:

```
data: <? echo json_encode($array) ?>,
```

Then in your `get_more_news.php` you can use this values as old plain `$_GET` vars (as your `method` is `GET`):

```
echo $_GET['x1'];
echo $_GET['x2'];
```

Comment: thanks a ton mate. Just two questions : 1) How I would fetch the data in get_more_news.php. Is it like : $_GET['x1'] ?   2.) what if I want to send multiple variables in the data part.

Comment: Updated my answer.